# Photos not ordered when selecting events or tags

Tags: shotwell, photo

**Shotwell rocks** ! Congrats to Yorba and his team.

I have a small issue with Shotwell 0.9.3.  When selecting specific "*Events*" or "*Tags*" (in the left bar), the photo's appearing in the main window do correspond with the selection **but** are no longer ordered in accordance with the order selected in "*View*", "*Sort Photos*".  This can be confusing.

For obtaining the visualisation of the photo's in the desired order, I need to change ("*View*", "*Sort Photos*", ...) the order (into an undesired order) and then immediately reselect the original (desired) order.  I suppose that after selecting a "*Tag*", the Shotwell code may have to automatically launch an ordering instance.

Answer (score 1):

There's sort of two answers here.

1. There was a bug that was in fixed in
   0.10 regarding ordering not working as expected.  Upgrading to 0.10 may
   solve this.  Ticket for this is
   here:
   http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/3539
2. Tags and events have a different
   sort order than other views.  This
   is a little confusing because it's
   not obvious by looking at the menu,
   but that's the way it works.

Comment: Many thanks Eric ! I will upgrade to 0.10 as suggested. Gr.