# Random photo order when selecting a tag

Tags: shotwell

My Shotwell library is ordered by descending date. When I click on a tag in Shotwell, the photos appear in an apparently random order. If I see the sorting options, descending date is selected. I have to select other option, and then go back to descending date, to get the order right.

If I then choose another tag, photos in the wrong order. If I go back to the first, they are right. But if I close Shotwell and launch it again, the sorting is wrong everywhere again.

This is exactly the same problem as this: [Photos not ordered when selecting events or tags](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46896/photos-not-ordered-when-selecting-events-or-tags)

But the solution given there, upgrading to 0.10, didn't work. I'm in fact in 0.11.1.

Any idea? Shotwell is really great for me, apart from this little nuisance. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a bug - the latest version is 0.11.2 - otherwise report a bug as per http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellFAQ#I-found-a-bug-in-Shotwell-How-can-I-report-it

Answer (score 2):

Great news -- this was already fixed in Shotwell 0.11.2!

More info on the bug report:
http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4030